# Forms not working / Jscript , PHP or HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created a site in html, but the email forms do not work. I don't know if it's from Js or php. I tried the GET method instead of POST in PHP . 
I changed the email address to the existing one . When I enter `<?php if(isset($_POST['contact_name']) != "contact_name"){` it will send email without name, email address, phone or message .It is the same for subscribers

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
   function checkcontact(input)
  {
   var pattern1=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
   if(pattern1.test(input))
   {
    return true;
   }
   else{
    return false;
   }
  }


  function validateSubscription(){


  var footer_name = document.getElementById("subscribe_name");  
  var footer_email_address = document.getElementById("subscribe_email");

  if(footer_name.value == ""){
  footer_name.className = "input error";
  return false;
  }
  else if(footer_email_address.value == ""){
  footer_email_address.className = "input error";
  return false;
  }
  else if(checkcontact(footer_email_address.value) == false){
  footer_email_address.className = "input error";
  return false;
  }  
  else{

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'process.php',
  data: $("#subscribe_form").serialize(),
  success: function(msg)
  {
  if(msg == 'success') 
  { 
  footer_name.className = "input";
  footer_name.value = "";
  footer_email_address.className = "input";
  footer_email_address.value = "";

  $("#subscribe_form").hide();
  document.getElementById("subscribe_success").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("subscribe_success").innerHTML = "Thank You! We'll contact you shortly.";
  }else{
  document.getElementById("subscribe_error").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("subscribe_error").innerHTML = "Oops! Something went wrong while proceeding.";
  }  
  }

  });

  }
  }

  function removeChecks(){
   var footer_name = document.getElementById("subscribe_name");  
   var footer_email_address = document.getElementById("subscribe_email");

   if(footer_name.value != ""){
    footer_name.className = "input";
   }
   if(footer_email_address.value != "" && checkcontact(footer_email_address.value) == true){
    footer_email_address.className = "input";
   }

  }


  function validateContact(){
   var errors = "";

   var contact_name = document.getElementById("contact_name");  
   var contact_email_address = document.getElementById("contact_email");
   var contact_phone = document.getElementById("contact_phone");

   if(contact_name.value == ""){
    errors+= 'Please provide your name.';
   }
   else if(contact_email_address.value == ""){
    errors+= 'Please provide an email address.';
   }
   else if(checkcontact(contact_email_address.value) == false){
    errors+= 'Please provide a valid email address.';
   }  
   else if(contact_phone.value == ""){
    errors+= 'Please provide a Phone No.';
   }


   if(errors)
   {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = errors;
    return false;    
   }

  else{

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'process.php',
   data: $("#contact_form").serialize(),
   success: function(msg)
   {
   if(msg == 'success') 
   { 
   document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("contact_name").value = "";
   document.getElementById("contact_email").value = "";
   document.getElementById("contact_phone").value = "";
   document.getElementById("message").value = "";
   $("#contact_form").hide();
   document.getElementById("success").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = "Thank You! We'll contact you shortly.";
   }else{
   document.getElementById("error").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Oops! Something went wrong while proceeding.";
   }  
   }

   });

   }
  }
```

```css
<?php
if(isset($_POST['contact_name']) != ""){
   $to = "abc@gmail.com";
   $from =  $_POST["contact_email"];
   $message = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Name: </strong>".$_POST["contact_name"]."<br />";
   $message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Email Address: </strong>".$_POST["contact_email"]."<br />";
   $message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Phone: </strong>".$_POST["contact_phone"]."<br />";
   $message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>Message: </strong>".$_POST["message"]."<br />";
   $subject = 'Contact Enquiry';  
   $headers = "From: ".$_POST["contact_email"]."\n";
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
   
   $send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 
 
 
 if($send)
 {
  echo "success";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "error";
 }
}


if(isset($_POST['subscribe_name']) != ""){
   $to = "abc@gmail.com";
   $from =  $_POST["subscribe_email"];
   $message = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Name: </strong>".$_POST["subscribe_name"]."<br />";
   $message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Email Address: </strong>".$_POST["subscribe_email"]."<br />";
   $subject = 'Newsletter subscription';  
   $headers = "From: ".$_POST["subscribe_email"]."\n";
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
   
   $send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 
 
 
 if($send)
 {
  echo "success";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "error";
 }
}


?>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 animate fadeInRight">
       <p class="success" id="success" style="display:none;"></p>
       <p class="error" id="error" style="display:none;"></p>
      
       <form class="contact-form" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return false">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" data-delay="300" placeholder="Numele tau " name="contact_name" id="contact_name" class="input">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" data-delay="300" placeholder="E-mail " name="contact_email" id="contact_email" class="input">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" data-delay="300" placeholder="Phone No" name="contact_phone" id="contact_phone" class="input">
         </div>
        </div>
        <textarea data-delay="500" class="required valid" placeholder="Mesajul tau" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="" type="submit" data-text="Trimite" onClick="validateContact();">Trimite</button>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly or it's super hard for us to read and follow the flow.

Comment: That's not how this works. You need to include _all_ relevant code _into the question itself_. The question (both text and code) also needs to e properly formatted so we easily can read it. If not, you're just making it harder for us to help you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your attention, please help me understand what i need to post (css, php and html are already posted). The point is that my contact forms don't work and I don't know where I should go. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved ! Problem was in .htaccess.
I replaced

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.((html)|(php))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([^.]+)$  $1 [R,L]
```

with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

In your Javascript for validateContact, you are comparing boolean against a string.

```
if(errors)
```

Should actually be

```
if(errors != '')
```

This is because errors will never be true or false, it will have a value or not have one.
Give that a go and it should solve your issue

Comment: `if (errors)` is perfectly valid in this context. If `errors` is an empty string, it will evaluate as false and if it contains a non empty string, it will evaluate as true.